# What is the issue in this VBScript script?

Tags: vbscript

```
username = InputBox("Enter user name below")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """c:\windows\CCM\PostDeploy\Bin\lin_ADcomputerjoin.exe""" & username
```

For some reason, this script failed on the last command, not sure why and how to fix it.

Comment: You missing a space between the `exe` and the `username` at the moment it will try to execute `"c:\windows\CCM\PostDeploy\Bin\lin_ADcomputerjoin.exe"someusername` which will fail when I think you want `"c:\windows\CCM\PostDeploy\Bin\lin_ADcomputerjoin.exe" someusername`. So just changing `""" & username` to `"" " & username` should fix it.

Comment: it looks like solve the issue, Thank you.  could you please let me know  if this vbscript has to run as adminsitrator, how and what could i add the script in?    The issue is : after i run the vbscript, it populate "windows script Host : Error : permission denied"

Comment: Likely due to UAC you'll need to run the script with Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the replying, the command actually is running under my account which has the Admin privilege already, but this command has to run it under the local admin rights  " C:\windows\system32" .  what would you recommend that i can fix this ? do you think if i create a batch file, run as admin, then use the batch file to run the vbscript work? or do you think i can place the admin credential inside this vbscript? thanks

Comment: Just open an elevated command prompt and run the VBScript using `cscript.exe /nologo "full path to script"`.

Comment: thanks again, Just one last thing. would you please tell me how can i do the send key in cmd.exe ? i like to combine both of them instead of typing the full path in cmd.             Dim objApp

set objApp = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
objApp.ShellExecute "cmd.exe",,, "runas",   1
                                                                               """send keys """                         cscript.exe /nologo "E:\Batch file\Planning\draft\test2.vbs""